# How to join two shapefiles and create a new shapefile using ArcObjects?

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects

Newbie in ArcObjects programming. Using C#. Developing a desktop application.

I have two shapefiles. One is a point shapefile Called **Addresses** and another Polygon shapefile which is called **Area**. The Address shapefile has an attribute called **Address_Number** while the Area shapefile has a attribute called **Area_Number**.

I need to select only the features that match "Address_Number" (from Addresses)  to "Area_Number" (from Area) and then create a new shapefile.

How can I do this?

Any help with some code example is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which direction do you want the join to be performed? The resulting shapefile can also have only one geometry field, either from the Address point or the Area polygon.

Comment: In fact, are you really trying to perform a join? It sounds as if you are actually trying to export only a subset of one table.

Comment: Resulting table should be a point geometry (Address point). Well actually I want to  select only the features that match "Address_Number" (from Addresses) to "Area_Number" (from Area) and then create a new shape file and get the AreaName into the new point shape file. Any code help would be greatly apprciated

Answer (score 1):

join the dbf from the area shape with a many to one, to the addresses shape. select the oid of area not null and export.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to do this. Can you give me some code example on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I apologize, I am not a programmer. I just know the steps I would use.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The text below assumes you want to perform an actual join, i.e. create a table containing fields from both source tables.

Since the two tables are in different data sources, you cannot perform a database join to do this. If you do not want to write code to do the join manually, you will need to use [IRelQueryTable](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRelQueryTable_Interface/00250000075s000000/) along with an [MemoryRelationshipClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MemoryRelationshipClassClass_Class/002500000mzt000000/). Both objects can be instantiated using their factories - [IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory_Interface/0025000004r6000000/) and [IRelQueryTableFactory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRelQueryTableFactory_Interface/00250000075t000000/). This will give a table which you can export anywhere you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried your steps but it failed. Looks like I'm doing something wrong. Any code help would be greatly appreciated.